# Как правильно написать конструктор?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как правильно написать конструктор, который будет создавать новые объекты и div`ы в разметке. Как правильно связать созданный объект  и div?

```
function Unit(name,life,monsterLeft,monsterBottom) {
    this.name = document.createElement('div');
    this.className = "monster";
    this.style.left= monsterLeft + "px";
    this.style.bottom= monsterBottom + "px";
    this.life = life;
    game.append(this);
    this.botRightXDistance = 10;
    this.botLeftXDistance = -10;
    this.botDownYDistance = -10;
    this.botUpYDistance = 10;
}
```

Comment: А для чего нужны botRightXDistance и остальные направления? Это случайно не размер создаваемого монстра?)

Answer (score 0):

Внутри конструктора, `this` ссылается на текущий создаваемый объект. Но никто не мешает внутри объекта - делать другой объект, или записать `let div = document.createElement('div'); this.html = div;` и обращаться к элементу через переменную `div.style...`

*this.botRightXDistance - у вас 4 раза повторяются названия, что намекает, что их можно сгруппировать в отдельный объект (или, как минимум, подумать об этом).

```js
const units = {};
const game = {
  append: function(unit) {
    document.body.appendChild( unit.node );
    units[ unit.id ] = unit;
  }
};

Unit.created = 0;
function Unit(obj = {}) {
  this.node = document.createElement('div');
  this.node.className = "monster";
  this.node.style.left = obj.left + "px";
  this.node.style.bottom = obj.bottom + "px";
  this.node.textContent = "•\\_/•";
  
  this.id = Unit.created++;
  this.name = obj.name || "bot_" + Unit.created;
  
  this.life = obj.life || 1000;
  
  this.bot_distance = {
    right_x: 10,
    left_x: -10,
    down_y: -10,
    up_y: 10,
  };
    
  game.append(this);
}

new Unit({life: 2000, left: 100, bottom: 70});
new Unit({life: 2000, left: 180, bottom: 30});
```

```css
.monster {
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```